# Access JSON data from Backbone Router

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

In my bb router I get some JSON data

```
$.ajax({
            url: "js/projects.json",
            success: function(projects) {

                database.projects = projects;

                var variables = {};
                var niz = new Array();
                var param = "Client"

                        $.each(projects, function()
                        {
                            if (!variables[this[param]])
                                variables[this[param]] = [];    
                            variables[this[param]].push(this);
                        });

                        for(var d in variables) {

                                niz.push(d);  

                                var number_of_clients = niz.length;
                        }

                        console.log(number_of_clients); 

                Backbone.history.start();
            }
        });
```

Now I wanna access this "projects" from one of my Views and to some stuff with that data , I know I can do the same thing again like here , but its duplicating code  , is there any way to get this data in View ? I tried a few things but with no success , I allways get the undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach your data to the window (window.projects = projects), then you can access it from everywhere. But I recomend you to use the ajax tools from Backbone, it's much easier and less messy.

Comment: Do you have any example of how to do that ? Or any good source for learning backbone ? Everything I've done so fare , I've done by myself  and some code snippets from the internet :>

Comment: This book is the ultimate reference : http://addyosmani.github.io/backbone-fundamentals/ Read the chapter about the basics and do the exercise 1, it should give a good idea of how to use Backbone.

Comment: I would also mention this awesome blog: http://lostechies.com/derickbailey/2011/12/27/the-responsibilities-of-the-various-pieces-of-backbone-js/

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, your question seems very suspicious design-wise. :)

Ajax calls should be made in models using the fetch function, not in a router, and not using jquery directly.

So I would advise you to redesign your app unless you have a strong reason not to do so.

Comment: I'm new in Backbone , that's the reason of this design :) Do you have any example of doing this in a model , or do you have some good source for learning backbone ?